# The Template Handler data is not showing in the web

Tags: go, web

Guys I am making a create your own adventure type book in which the user has options to select events. I am taking the story data from a json file. I have created two files named story.go and main.go where story.go handles all the functions and main.go has only the server. Look at the following codes

story.go

```
package gyg

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)

var defaultHandlerTemplate = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Give Yourself Goosebumps</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{.Title}}</h1>
    {{range .Paragraphs}}
        <p>{{.}}</p>
    {{end}}
    <ul>
    {{range .Options}}
        <li><a href="/{{.Chapter}}"> {{.Text}} </a></li>
    {{end}}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
`

var tpl *template.Template

type Story map[string]Chapter

type Chapter struct {
    Title      string   `json:"title"`
    Paragraphs []string `json:"story"`
    Options    []Option `json:"options"`
}
type Option struct {
    Text string `json:"text"`
    Arc  string `json:"arc"`
}

type handler struct {
    s Story
}

func init() {
    tpl = template.Must(template.New("").Parse("defaultHandlerTemplate"))
}

func JsonStory(r io.Reader) (Story, error) {
    d := json.NewDecoder(r)
    var story Story
    if err := d.Decode(&story); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return story, nil
}

func NewHandler(s Story) http.Handler {
    return handler{s}
}

func (h handler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := tpl.Execute(w, h.s["intro"])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "go-projects/gyg"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    filename := flag.String("file", "gopher.json", "the file with GYG story.")
    flag.Parse()

    f, err := os.Open(*filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    story, err := gyg.JsonStory(f)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    server := http.Server{
        Addr: "127.0.0.1:3000",
    }
    h := gyg.NewHandler(story)
    fmt.Printf("Startin the server on port %s\n", server.Addr)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(server.Addr, h))
}
```

On running main.go the server is listening on port 3000 but when opening port 3000 on browser, it's displaying

**defaultHandlerTemplate**

Comment: Your `server` is what's listening on port 3000, but your handler `h` is not associated to `server` in any way.

Comment: @Adrian what if assign Handler in the http.Server struct to h.

Comment: `... .Parse("defaultHandlerTemplate")` remove the double quotes from the variable's name and try again.

Comment: i.e. `tpl = template.Must(template.New("").Parse("defaultHandlerTemplate"))` should be: `tpl = template.Must(template.New("").Parse(defaultHandlerTemplate))`

Comment: Thanks, that is solved but now it's panicking, will check where its breaking

Comment: @two43pm in the template you're ranging over `.Options` and then, inside the loop, accessing `.Chapter`, *but* the type `Option` has no such field, and it seems that neither does it have such a method, therefore `"/{{.Chapter}}"` is your problem.

Comment: Yeah, in type its arc but in the template I had given it chapter, updated it and everything is working